# Spring sleuth Baggage key not getting propagated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing, brave

I've a filter (OncePerRequestFilter) which basically intercepts incoming request and logs traceId, spanId etc. which works well,
this filter lies in a common module which is included in other projects to avoid including spring sleuth dependency in all of my micro-services, the reason why I've created it as a library because any changes to library will be common to all modules.
Now I've to add a new propagation key which need to be propagated to all services via http headers like trace and spanId for that I've extracted current span from HttpTracing and added a baggage key to it (as shown below)

```
 Span span = httpTracing.tracing().tracer().currentSpan();
    String corelationId =
        StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getHeader(CORELATION_ID))
            ? "n/a"
            : request.getHeader(CORELATION_ID);
    ExtraFieldPropagation.set(CUSTOM_TRACE_ID_MDC_KEY_NAME, corelationId);
    span.annotate("baggage_set");
    span.tag(CUSTOM_TRACE_ID_MDC_KEY_NAME, corelationId);
```

I've added propagation-keys and whitelisted-mdc-keys to my application.yml (with my library) file like below

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation-keys:
      - x-corelationId
    log:
      slf4j:
        whitelisted-mdc-keys:
          - x-corelationId
```

After making this change in filter the corelationId is not available when I make a http call to another service with same app, basically keys are not getting propagated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your library you can implement ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent listener and add the configuration you need there 
Ex:

```
@Component
public class CustomApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LagortaApplicationListener.class);

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            log.debug("Custom ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent Listener");
            ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent envEvent = (ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event;
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = envEvent.getEnvironment();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("spring.sleuth.propagation-keys", "x-corelationId");
            props.put("log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys:", "x-corelationId");

            env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("custom", props));
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your microservice you will register this custom listener

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class)
                .listeners(new CustomApplicationListener()).run();      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've gone through documentation and seems like I need to add spring.sleuth.propagation-keys and whitelist them by using spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys

Yes you need to do this

> is there another way to add these properties in common module so that I do not need to include them in each and every micro services.

Yes, you can use Spring Cloud Config server and a properties file called `application.yml` / `application.properties` that would set those properties for all microservices

Comment: I've added propagation-keys and whitelisted-mdc-keys to application.yml but still it's not getting propagated also not sure why i need to add Sping Cloud Config server dependency.

Comment: Please check out this commit https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/commit/9c55edb3596e96e776dc35a052267f20b8483bcc  and this application for a working example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/tree/2.2.x . As for config server, you asked about a way that all applications have the configuration set without the need to do it separately for each application.

Comment: thanks @Marcin, but adding spring-cloud-config-server dependency and application.yml did not helped

Comment: You shouldn't just add the dependency, nor should you actually do it on your application side. Are you familiar with Spring Cloud Config idea? I told you how to leverage spring cloud config so as not to have the need to set those properties for each application. Please check the provided commit and code for more information. You have all the necessary details there with a working example.

Comment: thanks, got it working after adding spring cloud config and pointing my services to it to fetch properties.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mahmoud works great when you want register the `whitelisted-mdc-keys` programatically.

An extra tip when you need these properties also in a test, then you can find the anwser in this post: [How to register a ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent in Spring Test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094909/13718747)